# Group_by not matching ansible playbook groups as expected - how to use?

Tags: ansible

I am having trouble figuring out how to use `group_by` in my playbook. I have a role that's constrained to RHEL6, and I am interested in understanding how to use `group_by` to divide the RHEL6 machines from the RHEL5 machines. I have made a composite key, and in my debug task I can see that it is being properly set. But even even though the composite key being spit out by the debug task is “RedHat-6”, the playbook skips overs the section for `hosts: RedHat-6`

---

```
- hosts: abc
  user: myuser
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
     - group_by: key={{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_version | truncate(1, True, '') }}
     - debug: "msg={{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_version | truncate(1, True, '') }}"

- hosts: RedHat-6
  user: myuser
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
    - somerhel6onlyrole
```

(There is also a section for RedHat-5 in my playbook but it just calls `fail`)

I can't ever get the group_by host to match, it always skips. The output looks like:

```
TASK: [debug msg={{ansible_distribution}}-{{ansible_distribution_version | truncate(1, True, '')}}] ***
ok: [abchost1] => {
    "msg": "RedHat-6"
}
ok: [abchost2] => {
    "msg": "RedHat-6"
}

PLAY [RedHat-6] ***************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY [RedHat-5] ***************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

Am I using group_by wrong or misunderstanding the purpose of it? I am relatively new to ansible; the version I am using is 1.5.3. As well, I can solve the problem by simply validating in a different manner, but I would like to know how to use group_by properly. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You're close but you need to quote the key as follows:

```
tasks:
 - group_by: key="{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_version | truncate(1, True, '') }}"
```

This is due to a bug in the group_by module. The PR is here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/7273